# libpcap - pcap_findalldevs() causing memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, libpcap

I've been learning to use the libpcap library. Followed the manual, I had written the following code. It simply prints out all network interfaces on the local OS.

```c
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE] = {0};
    pcap_if_t *it = NULL;

    if(pcap_findalldevs(&it, errbuf) == 0) {
        while (it) {
            printf("%s - %s\n", it->name, it->description);
            it = it->next;
        }
        pcap_freealldevs(it);
    }
    else {
        printf("error: %s\n", errbuf);
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiled and run without issues. However, **valgrind** reported this simple code does have a memory leak:

```sh
$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./hello_pcap 
==1824== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1824== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1824== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1824== Command: ./hello_pcap
==1824== 
ens18 - (null)
any - Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces
lo - (null)
nflog - Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface
nfqueue - Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface
==1824== 
==1824== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1824==     in use at exit: 845 bytes in 31 blocks
==1824==   total heap usage: 45 allocs, 14 frees, 44,033 bytes allocated
==1824== 
==1824== 845 (40 direct, 805 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 16 of 16
==1824==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==1824==    by 0x48669A6: add_dev (pcap.c:1314)
==1824==    by 0x4866B77: find_or_add_dev (pcap.c:1266)
==1824==    by 0x4866C13: add_addr_to_if (pcap.c:1085)
==1824==    by 0x486345E: pcap_findalldevs_interfaces (fad-getad.c:266)
==1824==    by 0x48632CE: pcap_platform_finddevs (pcap-linux.c:1691)
==1824==    by 0x4866D65: pcap_findalldevs (pcap.c:721)
==1824==    by 0x1091AA: main (hello_pcap.c:10)
==1824== 
==1824== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1824==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==1824==    indirectly lost: 805 bytes in 30 blocks
==1824==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1824==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1824==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1824== 
==1824== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1824== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Which surprises me that I do call `pcap_freealldevs()` to try to free the memory, followed the [manual](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_findalldevs.3pcap.html):

> The list of devices must be freed with pcap_freealldevs(3PCAP), which frees the list pointed to by alldevs.

I seems `pcap_freealldevs()` doesn't work here? I wonder where I might do wrong?

I compiled the latest libpcap version 1.10 locally:

```sh
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/
total 3412
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2344310 Jun  4 04:25 libpcap.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       12 Jun  4 04:25 libpcap.so -> libpcap.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 Jun  4 04:25 libpcap.so.1 -> libpcap.so.1.10.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1131592 Jun  4 04:25 libpcap.so.1.10.0
```

And compiled the code as:

> gcc -g -Wall -o hello_pcap hello_pcap.c -lpcap

with gcc:

```sh
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
```

The OS is debian10 x64.

Thanks for help!

Comment: `it = it->next` changes `it` to the next element. When your loop finishes, `it` became `NULL` , and nothing is freed. You should save the pointer to the head element and free it.

Comment: @KagurazakaKotori Yes, I figured it out later in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the reason was due to a mistake I made in the code:

```c
int main()
{
...
    if(pcap_findalldevs(&it, errbuf) == 0) {
        while (it) {
            printf("%s - %s\n", it->name, it->description);
            it = it->next;
        }
        pcap_freealldevs(it);
    }
...
}
```

After the while loop finishes, **it** eventually becomes NULL. And thus no wonder **pcap_freealldevs()** doesn't work here if given a NULL pointer.

Adds a additional copy of the **pcap_if_t** pointer to do the while loop:

```c
int main()
{
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE] = {0};
    pcap_if_t *ift = NULL;

    if(pcap_findalldevs(&ift, errbuf) == 0) {
        pcap_if_t *it = ift;
        while (it) {
            printf("%s - %s\n", it->name, it->description);
            it = it->next;
        }
        pcap_freealldevs(ift);
    }
    else {
        printf("error: %s\n", errbuf);
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which free the memory correctly and fixed the memory leak issue. Thanks!